# How to fix "this.property is not iterable at window.onload" in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, this, object-literal

I have created an object literal in javascript using var keyword and assigned undefined properties and also methods. In the window.onload i first assigned values to properties then run methods, but in the run time they're still undefined.

```
window.onload = () => {
    obj.prop = ["a", "b"];
    obj.run();
};

var obj = {
    prop: undefined,
    run: () => {
        console.log(this.prop);
        for (let val of this.prop) {
            console.log(val);
        }
    },

};
```

The expected output should be :

```
"

["a","b"]

"a" 

"b"

"
```

but it shows the following :

```
undefined

TypeError : this.prop is not iterable at Object.run(?,the real object name is bloom but it errors "at Object.run") at window.onload
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of usage of the arrow function the "this" points to `Window`. You can't use that in an arrow function like you do.

Try to write your run function with the `function` keyword.

Example with function binding:

```
 window.onload = () => {
        obj.prop = ["a", "b"];
        obj.run();
    };

    var obj = {
        prop: undefined,
        run(){
            console.log(this)
            console.log(this.prop);
            for (let val of this.prop) {
                console.log(val);
            }
        },
    };
```